# MIPS delay subroutine

Tags: delay, mips, subroutine

I recently started using MIPS and am trying to do something simple. Currently, this program prints out Hello World without delay, and I want for it to print out Hello World with a 1 second delay.

```
.global myprog

.text
.set noreorder
.ent myprog 

myprog:
loop: 
    la      $a0,Serial
    la      $a1,hello
    jal     _ZN5Print7printlnEPKc        
    nop

    jal     mydelay
    nop

    j       loop
    nop

mydelay:
    li      $a2, 1000
    addi    $a2, $a2, -1
    bgez    mydelay     

    jr      $ra

.end myprog 

.data
hello:  .ascii "Hello, world!\0"
```

Basically running through this, it would print the first Hello World the first time, goes to "mydelay" when it hits that spot, in which mydelay would loop 1000 times (which should offer somewhat of a delay, not entirely sure about this part), and then it should return to the label loop, but currently all it does is print Hello World with no delay.

Comment: Your code prints (assuming `jal _ZN5Print7printlnEPKc` casuses printing) before your delay loop starts; what WOULD there be a delay?

Comment: Currently, there is NO delay, I'm trying to implement a delay. My reasoning is that once it prints, it will branch to the nodelay label, and after the delay has taken place, it will loop back to the beginning of the program. Essentially what I want to show up is           Hello World. (delay) Hello World. (over and over again.)

Comment: You CODED for no delay, whatever your desire might be, because you don't call the code TO delay until after you print for the first time, and then get stuck in an infinite loop (the `mydelay` loop, not the main `loop`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You re-initialize `$a2` with each iteration, so if your exit condition worked properly, the loop should be infinite.
2. The above suggests that your conditional branch is not correct; maybe `blez`?
3. Even if you do get your delay loop working, 1000 might be too small a count to be noticeable.

Comment: I want this to be an infinite loop for now, changed the conditional branch, and if i type 1000, does that mean 1000 milliseconds?

Comment: How long a very tight loop counting to 1000 takes depends on a lot of things, none of which you have spelled out.

Comment: @Soaps: You WANT the `mydelay` loop to be infinite?

Comment: As Scott said, it depends on a lot of things. You should take into account the frequency of the CPU, how compiler or even machine will transform and paralellize your loop at instruction level (might be 1000 (or more) times faster then expected if not done sequentially) etc.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a really bad approach for invoking a reliable delay. Always look for a `syscall` to see if there's something that already does it for you.

If you're using MARS, this will delay by 1000 milliseconds:

```
li $v0, 32
li $a0, 1000
syscall
```